# Use curl to post file from pipe

Tags: file, curl, post

How might i take the output from a pipe and use curl to post that as a file?

E.g. the following workds

`curl -F 'file=@data/test.csv'  -F 'filename=test.csv' https://mydomain@apikey=secret`

I'd like to get the file contents from a pipe instead but I can't quite figure out how to specify it as a  file input.   My first guess is `-F 'file=@-'` but that's not quite  right.

`cat data/test.csv | curl -F 'file=@-'  -F 'filename=test.csv' https://mydomain@apikey=secret`

(Here `cat` is just a substitute for a more complex sequence of events that would get the data)

**Update**
The following works:

```
cat test/data/test.csv  | curl -XPOST  -H 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data' --form 'file=@-;filename=test.csv' $url
```

Comment: How is it "not quite right" ?

Comment: @DanielStenberg The server was complaining that `req.file` didn't exist (Node/Express).  Hacking further adding the arguments `-XPOST -H 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data'` seemed to attach the data as the server expected

Comment: If you use `--trace-ascii -` you'll see that curl already use that Content-Type by default (and `-XPOST` doesn't help either). It was rather your fixed -F option that did the trick.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Very helpful.  Please post your comment as the answer so I can mark as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `--trace-ascii -` to the command line you'll see that curl already uses that `Content-Type` by default (and `-XPOST` doesn't help either). It was rather your fixed `-F` option that did the trick!